# Rails before filter not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Any reason why this before action would not redirect when @user is nil?

```
def set_user
  @user ||= User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to "/errors/404" unless @user
end
```

I can actually see it redirecting in the log (pasted below).

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/errors/404
```

but instead of rendering that error page and routing away from the controller action, it completes the action and causes an error saying @user is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`find`](https://devdocs.io/rails/activerecord/findermethods#method-i-find) method never returns `nil`. Instead, if a record with that ID doesn't exist, it throws an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

The easiest fix would be to use [`rescue_from`](https://devdocs.io/rails/activesupport/rescuable/classmethods#method-i-rescue_from):

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :redirect_to_not_found
  # Other code

  private
  def set_user
    @user ||= User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def redirect_to_not_found
    redirect_to "/errors/404"
  end
end
```

Now, the `redirect_to_not_found` method will be called whenever a user isn't found.